# How to address images in handlebars templates if the images are optimized with grunt-contrib-imagemin

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js, yeoman, gruntjs

I have created an ember app with yeoman and generator-ember.

```
yo ember
```

I have placed my handlebars templates in *app/templates* and the images in *app/images*. if I run

```
grunt server
```

everything looks fine. If I run

```
grunt server:dist
```

everything looks fine instead of the images I have addressed in my handlebars templates. It seems that the task **imagemin** or something else renames the images from something like *images/map.jpg* to something like *images/667de70e.map.jpg*. The img tags in my *index.html* file are corrected. But the img tags in my handlebars files like *templates/map.hbs* are still addressing the old path *images/map.jpg*.

How can I fix the path problem in my handlebars files? Is there a helper?

Comment: I have the same problem, somebody solved this?

Comment: Please post your gruntfile

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image address in ember templates grunt build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17779030/image-address-in-ember-templates-grunt-build)

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the `rev` task defined within `Gruntfile.js`. Don't think there's currently an straightforward solution for this, so I just comment out the line for renaming images:

```
// Gruntfile.js
// ...
rev: {
    dist: {
        files: {
            src: [
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                // '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}',
                '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any news in the meantime?

Answer (score 1):

Best explanation I've found is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/20433339/314631

In short, the grunt rev task works as expected for css background images but not for img src attr.