# Image address in ember templates grunt build

Tags: ember.js, gruntjs, build-process, yeoman

I used Yeoman to create a web app in EmberJS. Everything works ok, but after using the `grunt build` command, if I view the built app in the browser (from dist directory), I can see that some images are missing because the src path is wrong.

Grunt is changing the names of all images in the "image" folder, but not updating the paths in my HTML. It updates the path only in css files; the images in the .hbs template files still have the old path (with the old image name)...

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally i got rid of this:

all that is needed is to edit the Gruntfile.js in the project's root; the rev task is the one that manage image renaming; usually it is something like this:

```
rev: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/images/{,*/}*.{png,jpg,jpeg,gif,webp}',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

You just have to delete the row that tell him to process the images folder:

```
rev: {
        dist: {
            files: {
                src: [
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/{,*/}*.js',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css',
                    '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/fonts/*'
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

And it is done; all the images will keep their original names and so no path will be updated in css, html or hbs files...
Note that the rev task is only responsible for file renaming, not for compression (for images it is done by imagemin task) and so the images will be compressed in any case...

Comment: Thank you! I was just fighting with the same issue :)

Comment: I see the same thing, but this doesn't solve the root issue. I have views for my AngularJS app where I have images specified, and I would hope that the rev task would rename the paths in the dist directory's version of the app. Does anyone know how to get the rev task to work with templates/views?

Comment: @Swaraj, in my usemin task, I changed `html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html']` to `html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/views/{,*/}*.html']` which seemed to do the trick.

Comment: @Swaraj, has `ozandlb's` solution has solved your issue. If yes, then let me know, I am facing same problem but in Ember.js

Comment: @sumitramteke: I can't remember exactly what I did to get it working, but here is a gist of my full Gruntfile & package.json: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/bbff0f7a6f59b434c8d0. Hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

FWIW, I believe that the author of rev is being opinionated about something here: they're asserting that images should be included as CSS backgrounds, not via `img` tags. So, if your templates and views get all their images that way, you won't have any trouble.

IMHO, this is a pretty good convention to follow. Do everything with background images, and the problem should be solved across the application.

Comment: spot on, I moved my image src's to css background images and the rev task handled it as expected.

Answer (score 2):

You can transform the images url in the ember compiled template js... here's an example configuration of usemin that does this:

```
    usemin: {
        html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/{,*/}*.html'],
        css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
        options: {
            assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/css'],
            // The next pattern renames images within ember templates
            patterns: {
              js: [[/src=['"]([^"']+)["']/gm, 'Update the ember templates JS to reference our revved images']]
            }
        },
        js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/*.templates.js']
    }
```

Comment: this doesn't work for me on ember-generator v0.8. error ```Processing as JS - dist/scripts/7sd9af.templates.js Warning: undefined is not a function```

Comment: Perhaps go over https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin#patterns and try to make a simple example work... could it be an earlier usemin version?

Comment: @AndreasAndreou excellent solution! This solves the root of the problem and should be marked as the accepted answer. +1 from me!

Comment: @AndreasAndreou: please elaborate your answer, as i am facing `Running "usemin:js" (usemin) task

Processing as JS - dist/scripts/0a1c4b90.templates.js
Warning: undefined is not a function Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.`

Comment: @mrjedmao: as you are satisfied with this answer, it will be helpful if you provide us, how thus that help you in your work?

Comment: I'm using grunt-usemin@2.1.1 here, so haven't tried with latest (2.4.0)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
usemin: {
            html: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/**/*.html'],
            css: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles/{,*/}*.css'],
            js: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts/**/*.js'],
            options: {
                dirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts'],
                assetsDirs: ['<%= yeoman.dist %>', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/styles', '<%= yeoman.dist %>/scripts'],
                patterns: {
                    js: [
                        [/["']([^:"']+\.(?:png|gif|jpe?g))["']/img, 'Image replacement in js files']
                    ]
                }
            }
        }
```

From here:
[Grunt plugin for assets versioning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969422/grunt-plugin-for-assets-versioning)

The regex glob validates, as opposed to other solution shown here.

Also rolled back to use-min 2.1.1
npm install grunt-usemin@2.1.1 --save-dev

Although, I think 'assetsDirs' as opposed to just 'dirs' causes the undefined function error?