# How do you get grunt:rev to update img tags to match the filenames it changes?

Tags: gruntjs

So I have an img tag like so

```
<img src="images/loading.gif">
```

and I have loading.gif in the right place for it to be found by the test server.

grunt:rev copies and sets the `rev` of the file to be:

```
f42a62d8.loading.gif
```

How do I get the html to track that filename as loading.gif?

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this https://stackoverflow.com/a/20433339/314631

In short you grunt rev plays nicely with background image in css but not img src attr