# Grunt plugin for assets versioning

Tags: javascript, css, version, gruntjs

I'm looking for a grunt plugin that will automatically change the references to static assets (js/css) inside an html file like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css?v=12345678" />
<script src="script.js?v=12345678"></script>
```

I searched at the gruntjs.com/plugins -> "version", but it seems that all of them change the actual version of the files instead of references to them.

Am I missing it? Is there a plugin that can perform this task?

Answer (score 22):

For this I use [grunt-filerev](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev) for the versionning and [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) for the automatic update of the references in source files.

These two modules works well together (usemin replacing references with a mapping provided by filerev)

Hope this helps

**edit:** a few code examples (only showing you what's interesting in your case):

I use usemin & filerev only when packaging my app (for deployment) :

In the head of my index.html, the following code tell usemin to take all the files between the `build` tag and agregate it into one named `ie-shims.js`

```
[...]
<!-- build:js /js/ie-shims.js -->
    <script src="/vendor/html5shiv/dist/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="/vendor/respond/dest/respond.src.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
[...]
```

Next, in my gruntfile.js, i have two node :

```
[...]
filerev: {
    options: {
        encoding: 'utf8',
        algorithm: 'md5',
        length: 8
    },
    source: {
        files: [{
            src: [
                'www/js/**/*.js',
                'www/assets/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png,ico}'
            ]
        }]
    }
},
useminPrepare: {
    html: 'src/index.html',
    options: {
        dest: 'www'
    }
},

// usemin has access to the revved files mapping through grunt.filerev.summary
usemin: {
    html: ['www/*.html'],
    css: ['www/css/**/*.css'],
    js: ['www/js/**/*.js'],
    options: {
        dirs: ['www'],
        assetsDirs: ['www'],
        patterns: {
            js: [
                [/["']([^:"']+\.(?:png|gif|jpe?g))["']/img, 'Image replacement in js files']
            ]
        }
    }
} [...]
```

Finally, I have a grunt task that put all that together :

```
grunt.registerTask('build', 'Build task, does everything', ['useminPrepare', 'filerev', 'usemin']);
```

Then, the generated HTML is like that :

```
[...]
<script src="/js/ie-shims.9f790592.js"></script>
[...]
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. I read the documentation of these modules and tried to use them. They work, but it seems I have to create an additional destination folder which is not OK. Is it possible to keep html and js files in their own directories instead of moving them to a new directory? Please see the current structure of my project: http://pastebin.com/qcsaUBHC

Answer (score 2):

I found a neat post about keeping Grunt clean, that walks through an entire folder structure, Gruntfile.js config and task running, over at http://www.jayway.com/2014/01/20/clean-grunt/. Your comment on the earlier answer is about folder structure, so it should also help with that, since the structure there doesn't have index.html file in the root either.

1. Prep your html file as per the docs of `grunt-usemin` (and/or the post I linked)
2. You need to add `grunt-contrib-copy`, so you can copy index_src.html and rename it to index.html ([used this for inspiration](http://gotofritz.net/blog/geekery/rename-files-while-copying-grunt/)), and proceed with the 'usemin' task on that.
3. Change references to your assets to relative paths (ex. `../js/controller.js`)
4. Then configure your `Gruntfile.js` like this:

   ```
   [...]
   useminPrepare: {
       html: 'templates/index.html',
       options: {
           dest: 'js'
       }
   },

   // Concat - best to implement it this way for useminPrepare to inject the config
   concat: {
       options: {
           separator: ';'
       },
       // dist configuration is provided by useminPrepare
       dist: {}
   },

   // Uglify - best to implement it this way for useminPrepare to inject the config
   uglify: {
       // dist configuration is provided by useminPrepare
       dist: {}
   },

   filerev: {
       options: {
           encoding: 'utf8',
           algorithm: 'md5',
           length: 20
       },
       source: {
           files: [{
               src: [
                   'js/**/*.js'
               ]
           }]
       }
   },

   copy: {
     rename: {
       files: [
         {
           cwd: 'templates',
           src: ['**/index_src.html'],
           dest: 'templates',
           rename: function(dest, src) {
             return dest + src.replace(/_src\.html$/i, '.html');
           }
         }
       ]
     }
   },

   // usemin has access to the revved files mapping through grunt.filerev.summary
   usemin: {
       html: ['templates/index.html'],
       options: {
           assetsDirs: ['js']
       }
   } [...]
   ```

   I'm not a 100% sure about the regex to rename the file, but make a backup of the folder and give it a try. Also, I'm answering as per the pastebin link you gave, which did not include any css files. If there are any, things get a bit complicated, so let me know.
5. You could then use the grunt task Bixi suggested, but include your copy step (and concat & uglify)

   ```
   grunt.registerTask('build', 'Build task, does everything', [
   'useminPrepare',
   'concat',
   'uglify',
   'copy:rename',
   'filerev',
   'usemin'
   ]);
   ```