# Content versioning for angularjs with Asp.net

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

Does anybody know the best approach for versioning static content such as .html, .js, .cc, etc.  when using ASP.NET and angularjs.

So far the only thing I found is manipulating Etag in custom httpmodule.

Any ideas?

Comment: what is your build process? Are you using Grunt, Gulp or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Bundling and Minification in ASP.Net

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/bundling-and-minification

This will add versioning to your .jS and .CSS assets. It is a good starting point and can be extended with plugins or custom configuration/code to fit your needs.

There are plugins that support TypeScript, CoffeeScript, Less and Sass.

The other benefit to this is that as well as versioning your assets, this will bundle them together to reduce requests -- and minify them to reduce size.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but we can't use bundling for versioning because all .js and .css links are in index.html file.  And the main problem with .html files.

Comment: Is there a reason why you can't change the .html to .cshtml? This would allow you to use the bundling.

Comment: Dude, we have almost ready product which will be shipped soon, so yes, there is a reason :)

Comment: You cannot have an ASP.Net solution if you do not use ASP.Net. Only the pages that load the initial JS and CSS will need to have their file extension renamed to cshtml. Most likely this may be between 1 and a dozen pages. Infact changing them to CSHTML only means changing the script elements to @Scripts.Render() and making sure you have the proper Razor assemblies loaded.

Comment: Yes I can, have you heard about Web API? What about using Web API with angularjs? I told you already your solution wasn't an option.

Comment: WebAPI can't help with versioning of assets. It is purely for building RESTFul APIs. If you wan't to version your assets using the ASP.Net tools you need to use ASP.Net pages. Currently those use Razor for the template engine. If you are not going to use ASP.Net for versioning of assets you can create T4 templates that would generate your base HTML file with links containing the correct version hash. Another alternative to ASP.Net would be to use Grunt build task to version your assets http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21969422/grunt-plugin-for-assets-versioning

Answer (score 0):

You can use Grunt to build your js, css etc. All you need to do asset versioning is use [grunt-filerev](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev) and [grunt-usemin](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-usemin) plugins.
The first one will version files in the file system and the second one will update all static references throughout html and css to the versioned files.

I have done the same in a web.api / angularjs project using something as simple as:

```
   filerev: {
        options: {
            encoding: 'utf8',
            algorithm: 'md5',
            length: 8
        },
        all: {
            src: [
                '<%= project.dist %>/scripts/spa.min.js',
                '<%= project.dist %>/images/**/*.{jpg,jpeg,gif,png,svg,ico}',
                '<%= project.dist %>/styles/spa.min.css'
            ]

        },
    },
    usemin: {
        html: 'index.html',
        css: 'Content/**/*.css'
    },
```

Note: the above does revisioning. If you need to add a version number you can take a look at [grunt-version](https://www.npmjs.org/package/grunt-version) (I am doing revisioning with a banner on top of generated files with version and timestamp instead)